# Write bash script to dump postgres query result into file

Tags: bash

I want to dump the postgres query result into a file. but file is not created after executing the script.

output is:-

```
pg_is_in_recovery ------------------- t (1 row)
```

but file is not creating.

```
var=`psql -p 5430 -h localhost postgres cavisson_user <<Q
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
Q`

echo $var

echo "$var">file.txt
```

Comment: Do you have access to write in the current directory?

Comment: Also, you can use `tee` to print in stdout and in a file. I.e. `echo "$var" | tee file.txt`

Comment: yes, I have access to write in the file

Comment: File not creating at all or it's empty? But it still strange, because the script works for me. Also, can you try to add `echo "END"; cat file.txt` at the end of script?

Comment: now its working , I have changed 
echo "$var">file.txt to 
echo "$var" >>/home/cavisson/work/tmp/file